# matching certain numbers at the end of a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector of strings:

```
s <- c('abc1',   'abc2',   'abc3',   'abc11',   'abc12', 
       'abcde1', 'abcde2', 'abcde3', 'abcde11', 'abcde12', 
       'nonsense')
```

I would like a regular expression to match only the strings that begin with `abc` and end with `3`, `11`, or `12`.  In other words, the regex has to exclude `abc1` but not `abc11`, `abc2` but not `abc12`, and so on.

I thought that this would be easy to do with lookahead assertions, but I haven't found a way.  Is there one?

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to posters below for pointing out a serious ambiguity in the original post.

In reality, I have many strings.  They all end in digits: some in 0, some in 9, some in the digits in between.  I am looking for a regex that will match all strings *except* those that end with a letter followed by a 1 or a 2.  (The regex should also match only those strings that start with `abc`, but that's an easy problem.)

I tried to use negative lookahead assertions to create such a regex.  But I didn't have any success.

---

Thanks to all who replied and commented.  Inspired by several of you, I ended up using this combination: `grepl('^abc', s) & !grepl('[[:lower:]][12]$', s)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of one complicated regular expression, in this case I think it's easier to use two simple regular expressions:

```
s <- c('abc1',   'abc2',   'abc3',   'abc11',   'abc12', 
       'abcde1', 'abcde2', 'abcde3', 'abcde11', 'abcde12', 
       'nonsense')

s[grepl("^abc", s) & grepl("(3|11|12)$", s)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
s[grepl("abc.*(3|11|12)", s)]
[1] "abc3"    "abc11"   "abc12"   "abcde3"  "abcde11" "abcde12"
```

And the excluded strings are:

```
s[!grepl("abc.*(3|11|12)", s)]
[1] "abc1"     "abc2"     "abcde1"   "abcde2"   "nonsense"
```

---

**Edit:** As the comments indicate, there is some ambiguity in your requirements. A more comprehensive regex will test for the string start `^` and string end `$` and possibly only allow alphabet characters `[[:alpha:]]` before the final digits:

```
s[grepl("^abc[[:alpha:]]*.*(3|11|12)$", s)]
[1] "abc3"    "abc11"   "abc12"   "abcde3"  "abcde11" "abcde12"
```

---

You can also get `grep` to return the values directly, by passing the argument `value=TRUE`, thus saving a bit of duplication in the code:

```
grep("^abc[[:alpha:]]*.*(3|11|12)$", s, value=TRUE)
[1] "abc3"    "abc11"   "abc12"   "abcde3"  "abcde11" "abcde12"
```

Comment: I propose a slight modification: `grep("^abc.*(3|11|12)$", s, value=TRUE)`. `^` matches the beginning, `$` the end of the string, as the OP required.

Comment: That would also match things like abc33.

Comment: @Aust: judging from the question, abc33 should indeed be matched ("begin with abc and end with 3" - nothing about not ending with 33).

Comment: @StephanKolassa, technically the string ends with "3" but if you look at the number as a whole, it ends with "33" not "3". So it really depends on what the OP wants. I was just pointing out that it could go either way.

Comment: Could also use `grep( ..., value=TRUE)` and `grep( ..., value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)`.

Comment: @Aust: ah, for unambiguously worded requirements ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `substring` in this case too:

```
z <- nchar(s)
s[substring(s, 1, 3) == "abc" & substring(s, z) == "3" | 
    substring(s, z-1) %in%  c("12", "11")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking specifically for the requested numbers gives this:

```
n <-  c(3,11,12)

s[sub('abc[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+)$',s, replacement='\\1') %in% n]
 [1] "abc3"    "abc11"   "abc12"   "abcde3"  "abcde11" "abcde12"
```

This doesn't confuse 11 for 1:

```
 n <-  c(3,1,12)

s[sub('abc[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+)$',s, replacement='\\1') %in% n]
 [1] "abc1"    "abc3"    "abc12"   "abcde1"  "abcde3"  "abcde12"
```

For your edit, not ending in 1 or 2 (and using two regular expressions)

```
s[grepl('^abc',s) & !(sub('.*[^[:digit:]]([[:digit:]]+)$',s, replacement='\\1') %in% c(1,2))]
[1] "abc3"    "abc11"   "abc12"   "abcde3"  "abcde11" "abcde12"
```